# Windows 10: как сменить учетную запись Microsoft не заводя нового пользователя?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Установил сыну на компьютер Windows 10. Он пользуется компьютером уже несколько месяцев и наустнаваливал там кучу приложений. Там же там храниться у него куча файлов и проектов.
Недавно я обнаружил, что его учётка на его компьютере привязана к моей учетной записи Microsoft. Изначально учетная запись была локальной и к сети не привязанной. Но видимо в какой-то момент, при установке какой-то из программ понадобилось войти в учетную запись Microsoft и она привязалась.

Я хочу отвязать его компьютер от моей учетной записи. Хотелось бы сделать это без необходимости массового переноса установленных приложений и данных между учетными записями. То есть хочется избежать создания новой учетной записи.

Раньше вроде можно было как-то снова сделать учетную запись локальной, но сейчас я не могу найти как это можно сделать. Ну или может быть есть возможность привязать учетную запись на данном компьютере к учетной записи другого человека в Microsoft?

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/all/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA/e49286f3-94ff-44bb-b71f-61361f6e354b

Answer (score 1):

Из меню «Пуск» перейдите в «Параметры». Или вызовите это окно с помощью комбинации «WIN + I».

Войдите в раздел «Учетные записи», активируйте окно «Ваши данные».
В открывшемся подразделе выберите «Войти вместо этого с локальной учетной записи».

Появится поле, где нужно вбить пароль для подтверждения. Здесь же появится оповещение, что необходимо сохранить данные, открытые файлы, завершить текущую работу. Поскольку, чтобы удалить учетную запись Майкрософт, придется перезапустить компьютер и повторно войти в систему.

Затем появится окно, куда нужно вписать новые данные для новой локальной учетки. Введите имя пользователя, при необходимости создайте пароль, впишите подсказку для него.

Далее снова заходим в "Параметры", раздел «Учетные записи», активируйте окно «Электронная почта и учетные записи", кликаем по аккаунту Microsoft, нажимаем "Удалить"